# Why is the array behaving like this

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 6 and i want to post an array of JSON objects using a service class.
The following is my function

```
  getrerun(data,file){
  this.post=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {

        this.rerun.storeno=data[i].storeNo;
        this.rerun.filetype=data[i].loadtype;
        this.rerun.outboundsystem[0]=file;
        this.rerun.createdate=data[i].createdDate;
        this.post[i]=this.rerun;
        console.log("------>"+JSON.stringify(this.rerun)+"------->"+JSON.stringify(this.post));

    }
    this.newurl=this.devurl+"rerun";
    return this.http.post<any>(this.newurl,this.post); 

}
```

newurl is the url of the rest api that i want to hit and this.post is the array that i am sending

The value of data is following:

`[{"lastDate":"2019-02-20 12:36:27","storeNo":"G015","country":"SG","serviceStatus":"FAIL","createdDate":"2019-01-04 11:53:56","loadtype":"F"},{"lastDate":"2019-02-20 10:54:00","storeNo":"G121","country":"SG","serviceStatus":"FAIL","createdDate":"2019-01-23 16:29:33","loadtype":"F"}]`

and file is 'TP';

However the post array that I am getting is this:

`[{"outboundsystem":["TP"],"storeno":"G121","filetype":"F","createdate":"2019-01-23 16:29:33"},{"outboundsystem":["TP"],"storeno":"G121","filetype":"F","createdate":"2019-01-23 16:29:33"}]`

this basically means that both the entries in the array are the same i.e this.post[0].storeno is same as this.post[1].storeno. However, they should have two different values.

What do I do about this?

Comment: Your code always change fields of one object in each iteration. Just create new object per itertion.

Comment: the following is the  modification that i am making var rerun=new rerun(); this is now inside the for loop.However i am getting an error like this in my html view ":ERROR TypeError. rerun is not a constructor".  Rerun is a class which i have defined like this     export class rerun{
      storeno:any;
      filetype:any;
      outboundsystem:any[]=[];
      createdate:any;
      uiDate:any;
      
    }

Comment: @AshutoshKumar Please format the code properly and it would better to provide proper explanation on Expected and Current Output!

Comment: and yes i have imported rerun class in my codes as well

Comment: @PrashantPimpale....my bad.....rerun is an object whose attributes i am flooding through the code and then pushing that object in post array .But all the entries in my post array is being over ridden by the last entry.

Comment: thanks @AchmedzhanovNail...that worked